# Anything in Mac OS to interfere with using a disk through a USB hub?

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, usb

Have [Modbook Pro](http://modbook.com) with OS 10.10.2 and a powered seven-port USB hub.  A 750-GB bus-powered drive has no problems with the hub in-between.  But a powered drive with three partitions, one of them a Time Machine partition, always gets a failure in backup.  Works fine when the hub is not between.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about running OS X on non-Apple hardware.

Comment: A Modbook is modified Apple hardware, so it's on-topic here.

Comment: Have you tried a different hub? Does the drive work as expected otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

I have 4 USB 3 drives plugged into my MBP via a powered USB 3 hub and two of them have multiple partitions and different filesystems and all work just fine however the Modbook Pro does not yet support OS X 10.10, so that may be an issue.

From [Modbook Support Center](http://www.modbook.com/support):

> YOSEMITE UPDATE
>
> OS X Yosemite Not Currently Supported on the Modbook Pro The newest
>   version of the OS X operating system, Yosemite (OS X 10.10), is not
>   fully supported on the Modbook Pro.
>
> We do not recommend upgrading your Modbook Pro to Yosemite at this
>   time. (Both OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion and 10.9 Mavericks are supported
>   on the Modbook Pro.)
>
> An update to the Modbook Pro System Software and the Modbook Pro Pen
>   Tablet Software offering compatibility with Yosemite and other
>   features will be available in the near future. Check back here
>   occasionally for updates.

Comment: That warning merely refers to their incompetence in supporting the digitizer.  They should not have any effect on disk drives.  Although, the digitizer does use the other USB port …